# Retrieve index of selected row in j2me TableItem

Tags: netbeans, java-me

I'm using `org.netbeans.microedition.lcdui.TableItem` for a j2me mobile application and i have trouble on retrieve index of the row "selected" by the user in a `TableItem`.

I know there is  `getSelectedCellRow()` but if i don't select any row or if i select the first row the method returns always zero so i don't know in which case i'm in.

In which way have you solved ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to know that the `Tableitem` is not a part of standard API. You can check it out [here](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html) and we implement it like this,  [class TableItem](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/IDE-Netbeans/vmd.analyzer/org/netbeans/microedition/lcdui/TableItem.java.htm), as you can see here, `getSelectedCellRow()` actually returns `cursorCellX;` and if you go through the implementation you can find yourself the reason for your question,why it returns `zero`.

Comment: Thanks, but so there is no way to know the selected row ?